# Issue while reading from Stream in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, stream, network-programming

I have a small UWP app which uses a *StreamSocket*. The socket is accessed via using the *socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead()* method.

This works fine for nearly all sizes of incoming data (10 bytes to 6,000 bytes). But when using the overload with a buffer size the socket hangs when more data is received. So 6000 bytes are no longer received if the buffer is set to 4096. Even when reading the data in chunks of 10 bytes it does not work. The method *ReadAsync* hangs forever.

I am not sure if this is a bug. I would expect that I can still receive the data. If not I need to know the default size or behavior of that buffer.

Example code:

```
StreamSocket socket = InitSomewhere();
var readStream = socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead(500);
var buffer = new byte[100]
readStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 100) // Hangs here if received > 500!
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Best regards, Christan

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I can not reproduce this issue in my side using the official [StreamSocket](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/StreamSocket) sample.

On the other hand, you can try to use the [DataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.datareader) class to read the data as the above sample.

```
private async void OnConnection(
    StreamSocketListener sender, 
    StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    DataReader reader = new DataReader(args.Socket.InputStream);
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // Read first 4 bytes (length of the subsequent string).
            uint sizeFieldCount = await reader.LoadAsync(sizeof(uint));
            if (sizeFieldCount != sizeof(uint))
            {
                // The underlying socket was closed before we were able to read the whole data.
                return;
            }

            // Read the string.
            uint stringLength = reader.ReadUInt32();
            uint actualStringLength = await reader.LoadAsync(stringLength);
            if (stringLength != actualStringLength)
            {
                // The underlying socket was closed before we were able to read the whole data.
                return;
            }

            // Display the string on the screen. The event is invoked on a non-UI thread, so we need to marshal
            // the text back to the UI thread.
            NotifyUserFromAsyncThread(
                String.Format("Received data: \"{0}\"", reader.ReadString(actualStringLength)), 
                NotifyType.StatusMessage);
        }
    }
```